# How topojson's world map scale has set?

Tags: d3.js, geospatial, topojson

in [world-110m.json](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/examples/world-110m.json)

there is a scale value.
`[0.0036000360003600037, 0.0017364686646866468]`

and I got this values are computed from `[360/99990, 173.64513/99999]`

ok, `360` from latitude, `173.64` from longitude, just for including northernmost lang point.

but where does that denominators (`99990` and `99999`) came from?

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson-specification#212-transforms

Comment: well, what i wanted to know was "how those specific denominators derived", not "what that number means"

Comment: Oh wait. I moved a small step of understanding. cause to get maximum efficiency of quantization, numbers should be 99999. and... oh.

Answer (score 0):

First, My calculation was wrong. it was `[360/99999, 173.64513/99999]`

so both denominators are 99999: the most biggest 5-digit number, is the most efficient number for quantization.